# html object tag issue (scrollbar on mouseover)

Tags: jquery, html, object, mouseover

I have a webpage where dropdown menus are at the left side of page. Once i click a particular link from the dropdown menu, this function executes.

(updated with the correct syntax.)

```
$('panel').html("<object data='output.html' type='text/html'></object>");
```

This report gets shown then at the right side of the page. It has a scrollbar since the data present in the page is too long to fit in screen. If user just hovers over this scrollbar and moves the mouse away from it, the scrolling starts. It should not scroll becauase the user didnt intend to go to below part of the page.

I want to disable this scrollbar mouseover feature but i have no idea where this had come from.

I checked jquerys .html function and object tag online but couldnot find much from it. I am sure the scroolbar is created in the fly by the html object tag. can someone shed some light here ??

as per the update from spencer and PHPglue, i guess i have to work on the css part of the scrollbar. however overflow:hidden will just remove the scrolling option. i want it to be there. its just that the scrolling occurs at mouseover or when the mouse hovers over the scrollbar. how can i stop this ??

Comment: You're missing quotes around your HTML attributes. `"'$url/web"? This is not PHP.

Comment: @PHPglue- updated. yea, its not PHP. $url/web was a path mentioned in perl. Tat is not necessary. So i have removed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is like a complete workaround where i eliminated object tag. used iframe instead and it worked pretty well for me. The scrollbar of the page does scroll only when i click on the scroll and move it down. doesnot randomly scrolls when i just mouseover or hover the scrollbar as in the object tag.

hope it helps someone. Thanks Here is that code

```
$("#panel").html('<iframe id ="myobject" src="output.html"></iframe>');

 #myobject {
            width:100%;
            height:101%;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a syntax error:

```
$('panel').html("<object data='output.html' type='text/html'></object>");
```

Note that height and width are pixels in an object. Use CSS for style anyways.

Comment: @PHPglue- i dont think it is a syntax error. My code works and gives me output. However the issue is the scrollbar which i get once the page is display by object tag

Comment: CSS `overflow:hidden` is  your friend.

Comment: @PHPglue- Could you please let me know where i should use this ? the html page gets created dynamically....

Comment: That depends where the overflow is occurring.

Comment: @PHPglue- the overflow:hidden is to remove the scrollbar completely. i dont want to remove it. i just want to disable the scrollbar when mouseover takes place

Comment: Try something like `$('#whateverYouScroll').mouseenter(function(){$(this).scrollTop();});`.

Answer (score 1):

You have un-escaped quotes here `'output.html'`, but an easier way to fix it is to remove the unneeded double quotes on the outside and use single quotes on the inner part of the string:

```
$("panel").html('<object data="output.html" type="text/html" width=100% height=99%></object>');
```

Comment: Comma and quote issues still.

Comment: @Spencer- my issue is after the html page gets displayed. :( The code works and data gets displayed.